# What is a StraightforWord™?

Tags: word, pattern, word-property

*This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee)*

If a word satisfies a certain property it is called a **StraightforWord™**. If not, it is called a **Convoluted Word™**. Here are some examples:

| Convoluted Words™ | StraightforWords™ |
| --- | --- |
| FORWARDS | BACKWARDS |
| FEW | MANY |
| DEAD | LIVE |
| LIVELOCK | DEADLOCK |
| CHILD | PARENT |
| REDUCE | OXIDISE |
| DICTIONARY | THESAURUS |
| MALAYSIA | SINGAPORE |
| REINSTATE | MONICA |
| LOUSY | MEME |

CSV:

```
Convoluted Words™,StraightforWords™
FORWARDS,BACKWARDS
FEW,MANY
DEAD,LIVE
LIVELOCK,DEADLOCK
CHILD,PARENT
REDUCE,OXIDISE
DICTIONARY,THESAURUS
MALAYSIA,SINGAPORE
REINSTATE,MONICA
LOUSY,MEME
```

What is the rule to tell whether a word is a StraightforWord™ or not? Why is it called a StraightforWord™?

(Note that each word can be tested for whether it is a StraightforWord™ on its own, without looking at any of the other words in the list of examples.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A word is StraightforWord™ if it

> has exactly four letters which are made from straight line segments only.

Only StraightforWord™s fit this pattern

> B**A**C**KWA**RDS
>  **MANY**
>  **LIVE**
>  D**EA**D**L**OC**K**
>  P**A**R**ENT**
>  O**XI**D**I**S**E**
>  **THE**S**A**URUS
>  S**IN**G**A**POR**E**
>  **M**O**NI**C**A**
>  **MEME**

Comment: So the correct spelling is StraightFourWord.

Comment: That may be too straightforward. If you write What's up, then WHAT is a StraightforWord™, so the title's true.